# Using Git subtree with turborepo

Tags: git, access-control, monorepo, git-subtree, turborepo

**Looking for an opinion**

I am using [turborepo](https://turborepo.org/) for one of my Vue projects. Currently I have a situation at my organization.
We have setup a monorepo(turborepo) for a client/server web application. and want to hire a contractor to work on the design of some part of the client. We intend to give access to only relevant code to the contractor.

We have tried for several solutions and found `git subtree` to be ideal candidate in this situation.

What are your general thoughts on using monorepo (turborepo) with `git subtree` ?

Comment: hey @power, I am trying to do this with `git subtree` but how are you able to connect the `packages` from the main tree to the subtrees in the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `git subtree` in turborepo monorepo for initial migration of existing code in order to preserve git history. After initial migration managing code in multiple repos can add overhead and confusion. But in your case it could make sense to meet you granular access requirements.